# How to calculate amount of reflected light from a retro reflective tape at a distance

Tags: visible-light, reflection, laser

If retro-reflective [tape is reported to be 1000 cd/lux/sq m reflective](https://scihub.bban.top/10.4271/2015-01-1429) at some angle, how much of initial light can be measured at some arbitrary distance? That is if I shine a 5mW laser beam at the tape what percentage of that beam is reflected back?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm:

$$ R_A = 1000\,{\rm cd/lx/m^2} $$

where a lux (illuminance) is a lumen per square meter means:

$$ R_A = 1000\,{\rm cd/(lm/m^2)/m^2}  = 1000\,{\rm cd/lm} $$

and a lumen (luminous flux) is a candela-steradian:

$$ R_A = 1000\,{\rm cd/(cd\cdot sr)} = 1000\,{\rm sr}^{-1}$$

which *probably* means it is 1000/4$\pi$ times brighter that isotropic re-radiation of the incoming power (per unit area).

(Note: this is how radar backscattering is quantified, in which case one would say $\sigma_0 = 30\,$dB).

Checking with The International Commission on Illumination (http://eilv.cie.co.at):

$$ R_A \equiv \frac R A $$

where the coefficient of luminous intensity

$$ R \equiv \frac I {E_{\perp}}$$

is the quotient of the luminous intensity, $I$, of the retroreflector in the direction of observation by the illuminance, $E_{\perp}$ , at the retroreflector on a plane perpendicular to the direction of the incident light.

$I$ is the quotient of the luminous flux, dΦv, leaving the source and propagated in the element of solid angle, dΩ, containing the given direction, by the element of solid angle

$$I = \frac{d\Phi}{d\Omega}$$

Unit: cd = lm·sr -1

where $\Phi$ is the quantity derived from the radiant flux, Φe, by evaluating the radiation according to its action upon the CIE standard photometric observer

Unit: lm

Meanwhile:

$$E_{\perp} = \frac{d\Phi}{dA}$$

is quotient of the luminous flux dΦv incident on an element of the surface containing the point, by the area dA of that element.

Which agrees with the original hypothesis (with a factor of 2, because it is possible that the illumination engineers have built in a hemi-sphere assumption).

Comment: A lot of unfamiliar terms :) 
If the angle of the illumination source is perpendicular to the retro-reflective surface. And given say 1000 cd/lux/sqm and 5mW laser source, where these numbers should to be pluged in to get the rate of reflection?